# Does your app access location in the background in APK?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can someone explain what this question actually means and if it's safe to say no this question

*Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)?*

- I do have these permissions in android manifest

  ```
  - <uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  ```
- I DONT have at all ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in the android manifest
- I ask permission when the app is first installed

[image]

Question
Is it safe to say that the app does not access location in the background?

Thanks for your time and appreciate your prompt response!!

**Update**

App Target android
MIN Android 6 Target Android 9 ( old app)

Comment: *" Is it safe to say that the app does not access location in the background?"* - what about the second half of the question "... or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)?"? Project properties / Android Manifest / Minimum Android version -- what is your setting there?

Comment: Min android version 6 target 28. Is an old app not updated for a while and now noticed that uses a thirdy party geocrosslocation with allobackground set to true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your app's manifest, check for the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission and the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Verify that your app requires these location permissions.

Second, If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, also check for the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission. Verify that your app has a feature that requires it.

Third, looking for use of location access APIs, such as the `Fused Location Provider API`, `Geofencing API`, or `LocationManager API`.

Last, If your app uses an SDK or library that accesses location, this access is attributed to your app. To determine whether an SDK or library needs location access, consult the library's documentation.

Comment: Hi - it requires the Access_Coarse_Location and Access_Fine_Location - it does not use Background location as its Android 28 . How can I actually check if is accessing location in the background. Is there a physical test I can do

Comment: If app is accessing the location in the background, the gps icon will show on the top states bar. Or you can check which app used gps in settings. But I have no idea about physical test.

Comment: that is a good one . when the app goes in the background the gps icon dissapears! Meaning no access to background location. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes , that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the gps icon dissapearing when in background did it for me as a tip